# Firefox Performance Problems

Tags: firefox-extensions

Does anyone know what I should be checking if Firefox keeps on slowing down and stalling? I'm still using it over Chrome because I've got so many useful extensions but I think one or more of them are now causing problems with my browsing. Is there any error or event log I can check?

Also, I recently installed the Google Toolbar, has anyone had problems after installing it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error console in Firefox; see menu tools/error consle.
You could disable all extensions and then re-enable them one by one to see who's causing problems.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J to bring up the error console. Also, there might be some properties that need to be turned on - in about:config - javascript.options.showInConsole

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the resource consumptions of firefox ? do you used to have a lot of tabs open ? I think it is a well known problem (memory leak) which can be alleviated http://blog.skdev.net/2009/02/12/how-to-fix-firefox-memory-leak-problem/

Whenever my firefox process reach over 500Mb to consume, I used to recycle it.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to call that a "leak", it just seems to be a large cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a snappy Firefox that comes up in 1 second on an SSD take around 30 seconds to come up because of some Gmail-related extension.

Some extensions (AdBlock, etc.) slow down browsing and everything, and it's not a Firefox issue.

Your solution?

#### Turn off ALL extensions, then enable them one by one, and see which one causes this.

If that didn't work, you might have a virus. :P